# How can I make sure that my Nextjs app only renders IOS emojis on all kind of devices?

Tags: ios, reactjs, next.js, emoji

I am using Emojis on my website developed using next.js. Currently, I display the emojis by copy and pasting them as a string into my Emoji component displayed below:

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  symbol: string;
  label: string;
}

const Emoji = ({ symbol, label }: Props) => (
  <span
    className="emoji"
    role="img"
    aria-label={label ? label : ""}
    aria-hidden={label ? "false" : "true"}
  >
    {symbol}
  </span>
);

export default Emoji;
```

The problem is that my website shows different kind of emojis depending on the users device. Sure, it makes sense because emojis are unicode which is interpreted differently depending on the device.

How can I make sure that my nextjs app only renders IOS emojis on all kind of devices? And this without making any CDN calls. Just all logic managed locally on my server.

Thank you for your help!

What did I tried so far to solve this issue?

I read a lot of articles and researched on google for solutions but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: iOS emoji glyphs are copyrighted, you cannot legally use them on other platforms without Apple's permission.

Comment: oh, I have not thought on that! Thank you very much Tamás Sengel! Are there any free to use emojis that I can utilize in my app? The goal is to make the view identical on all devices. And then the same question remains, how to do it?

Comment: Check out https://openmoji.org/